# Need strategy for implementing single-source of reusable web applications

Tags: oop, templates, web-applications, model-view-controller, coldfusion

I'm mostly a frontend designer/dev who's inherited some outdated ColdFusion applications and I'm trying to clean them up and make them easier to maintain. Because of my limited exposure to OOP/MVC/et al., I'm not sure where to even start and I'm hoping someone can give me clear direction. Here's the issue:

We currently have many common "applications" that are re-used for every client on our web server. Examples of these are "Registration", "Survey", etc. Each of these individually is a directory on our server that contains all the code required to run them and is customized for each client. When we need to implement a new "Registration" application for a new client, we simply copy the entire source and paste it into that new client's directory. It works, but every client needs its own alterations to the applications, and it's a nightmare to maintain.

I would really like to step away from that and use a single source base for the "Registration" application, but I'm not sure how to get there.

(I've used CFC's briefly before and believe this may be a part of the answer, but I've only used them as individual components on a single page. I'm not sure how I would use these to build multi-page web applications.)

Side note: I've worked briefly with Magento templates and really liked the concept of how that worked - the source is located in one place, and to overwrite or modify them you simply recreate that file in your custom theme directory. Something like this would be ideal to be able to maintain the small variations between each client, but I have no idea where to begin to build something like that.

I realize my question may be a bit too vague. I'm not sure which questions to ask. Please help me narrow down my questions if you can. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to ask specific questions, and ones that have concrete answers. What you have currently will result in opinion based answers..which are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: Can you help me rephrase the question into something that will help get me started?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of: "What do I need to learn in order to implement multiple instances of an app using a single source in ColdFusion?"

Comment: So, you want someone to write the question for you, and then have other people answer it? :D

Comment: I understand your concern with the rules of SO, and I was simply attempting to follow them by trying to rephrase the question. Haven't you ever had a problem in which you weren't sure how to even ask for help? I'm doing my best to describe my issue but I'm not even sure where to begin or what path to go down. Russ's answer about OOP is enough to get me started.

Comment: Happens to me every day, but I have never asked for someone to re-write my question for me.

Comment: I don't think this question really can be re-worded in a way that wouldn't be asking a question that is either too broad or too opinionated. Maybe that's why you don't know how to ask it.

Comment: Any suggestions for a good dev community that is more appropriate for broader questions such as these?

Comment: Isn't this basically asking "an you write my application for me?" and expecting said application to be posted in a text box on StackOverflow? Isn't that incredibly unlikely proposition? Voting to close for being "too broad".

Comment: I have not asked anybody to write my application for me. I understand this is a broad question. I was simply asking for a broad answer; a starting point, a strategy, even if there are multiple options. Russ understood my situation perfectly and gave me a few suggestions. That's all I wanted. I apologize if this is the wrong community for that kind of question (I'd like to know what is), but Russ and Dan helped me out and I'm sorry to have wasted everyone else's time. Topic closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to refactor your code base so that it is more reusable. There are various ways to accomplish this, but you'll need to start by identifying all of the common code (that is not client-specific). Then you'll probably want to reorganize it into collections of functions and/or components that will likely be placed in a parent folder to all of the client-specific code so that it can be easily shared. 
I recommend slowly migrating code to the common code base, starting with simple functions first. 
You will likely need to familiarize yourself with object oriented programming in Coldfusion in order to fully modularize the code base.

Comment: The various ways include CFCs which was mentioned in the question, custom tags, and included files (cfinclude tag).  I suggest familiarizing yourself with each concept and picking the most appropriate one for each piece of re-useable code.  You don't have to pick the same one for each chunk of code.